# Can't get Fabric's detached screen session example to work

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to execute a script on a remote host using a detached screen session. I tried out the [example Fabric gives](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang) and unfortunately couldn't get it to work.

```
from fabric.api import run

def yes():
    run('screen -d -m "yes"')
```

Executing `fab yes` on my local machine correctly connects it to the remote host and says the command has been run, however nothing is executed on the remote host. Trying `screen -d -m "yes"` on either machine works as expected.

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it. Also, on a side note, why are there quotes around the yes in the command? Would it work without the quotes? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`run('screen -d -m yes; sleep 1')` works.

Not sure if Fabric or screen are to blame for this behaviour though.

Answer (score 4):

Although AVB answer is perfect I'll add a small tip which may help someone like me. If you want to run more than one command put them to a executable file.

This will not work:

`run('screen -d -m "./ENV/bin/activate; python run.py; sleep 1"')`

So create a run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ENV/bin/activate
python run.py
```

And use it like `run('screen -d -m ./run.sh; sleep 1')`

Comment: why is the "sleep 1;" there?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
run('sudo screen -d -m python app.py && sleep 1', pty=True) 

screen -d -m
```

Start a session that starts in disconnected mode

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer so others can understand easily.