# Background "atop" process from python script executed remotely with Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, background-process, fabric, nohup

### Context

I'm adding a few pieces to an existing, working system.
There is a control machine (a local Linux PC) running some test scripts which involve sending lots of commands to several different machines remotely via SSH.  The test framework is written in **Python** and uses **Fabric** to access the different machines.

All commands are handled with a generic calling function, simplified below:

```
def cmd(host, cmd, args):
    ...
    with fabric.api.settings(host_string=..., user='root', use_ssh_config=True, disable_known_hosts=True):
        return fabric.api.run('%s %s' % (cmd, args))
```

The actual commands sent to each machine usually involve running an existing python script on the remote side. Those python scripts, do some jobs which include invoking external commands (using `system` and `subprocess`). The `run()` command called on the test PC will return when the remote python script is done.

At one point I needed one of those remote python scripts to launch a background task: starting an openvon server and client using `openvpn --config /path/to/config.openvpn`. In a normal python script I would just use `&`:

```
system('openvpn --config /path/to/config.openvpn > /var/log/openvpn.log 2>&1 &')
```

When this script is called remotely via Fabric, one must explicitly use `nohup`, `dtach`, `screen` and the likes to run the job in background. I got it working with:

```
system("nohup openvpn --config /path/to/config.openvpn > /var/log/openvpn.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &"
```

The [Fabric FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/faq.html) goes into some details about this.
It works fine for certain background commands.

### Problem: doesn't work for all types of background commands

This technique doesn't work for all the commands I need. In some scripts, I need to launch a background `atop` command (it's a `top` on steroids) and redirect its stdout to a file.

My code (note: using `atop -P` for parseable output):

```
system('nohup atop -P%s 1 < /dev/null | grep %s > %s 2>&1 &' % (dataset, grep_options, filename))
```

When the script containing that command is called remotely via Fabric, the atop process is immediately killed. The output file is generated but it's empty. Calling the same script while logged in the remote machine by SSH works fine, the `atop` command dumps data periodically in my output file.

Some googling and digging around brought me to interesting information about background jobs using Fabric, but my problem seems to be only specific to certains types of background jobs. I've tried:

- [appending sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327649/cant-get-fabrics-detached-screen-session-example-to-work)
- [running with pty=False](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/395)
- replacing `nohup` with `dtach -n`: same symptoms
- I read about [commands like top failing in Fabric with stdin redirected to /dev/null](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/216#issuecomment-1846789), not quite sure what to make of it. I played around with different combinations or (non-) redirects of STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR

Looks like I'm running out of ideas.

Fabric seems overkill for what we are doing. We don't even use the "fabfile" method because it's integrated in a `nose` framework and I run them invoking `nosetests`. Maybe I should resort to dropping Fabric in favor of manual SSH commands, although I don't like the idea of changing a working system because of it not supporting one of my newer modules.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, looks like it is working

```
from fabric.api import sudo

def atop():
    sudo('nohup atop -Pcpu 1 </dev/null '
        '| grep cpu > /tmp/log --line-buffered 2>&1 &',
        pty=False)
```

result:

```
fabric:~$ fab atop -H web01
>>>[web01] Executing task 'atop'
>>>[web01] sudo: nohup atop -Pcpu 1 </dev/null | grep cpu > /tmp/log --line-buffered 2>&1 &
>>>
>>>Done.

web01:~$ cat /tmp/log 
>>>cpu web01 1374246222 2013/07/20 00:03:42 361905 100 0 5486 6968 0 9344927 3146 0 302 555 0 2494 100
>>>cpu web01 1374246223 2013/07/20 00:03:43 1 100 0 1 0 0 99 0 0 0 0 0 2494 100
>>>cpu web01 1374246224 2013/07/20 00:03:44 1 100 0 1 0 0 99 0 0 0 0 0 2494 100
...
```

The atop command may need the super user. This doesn't work

```
from fabric.api import run

def atop():
    run('nohup atop -Pcpu 1 </dev/null '
        '| grep cpu > /tmp/log --line-buffered 2>&1 &',
        pty=False)
```

On the other hand this work.

```
from fabric.api import run

def atop():
    run('sudo nohup atop -Pcpu 1 </dev/null '
        '| grep cpu > /tmp/log --line-buffered 2>&1 &',
        pty=False)
```