# Trying to launch a process via screen from within ansible

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant, gnu-screen, ansible

I'm having a slightly weird, repeatable, but unexplainable problem with `screen`.

I'm using `ansible`/`vagrant` to build a consistent dev environment for my company, and as a slightly showy finishing touch it starts the dev server running in a `screen` session so the frontend devs don't need to bother logging in and manually starting the process, but backend devs can log in and take control.

However, one of the systems - despite being built from scratch - ends up with an immediately dead screen (it doesn't log anything to screenlog). Running the command manually works fine.

(the command being)

```
screen -L -d -m bash -c /home/vagrant/run_screen_server.sh
```

I've even gone to the point of nuking everything vagrant/virtualbox related on the system, making sure it's installing a clean, nightly box. Exactly the same source box works all the other machines.

Are there any other debugging steps I can be taking or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: So, all the machines are the same? and you are saying that one of them is failing and the other ones are just fine ?

Comment: They were different(ish) machines, but they had all the same versions of the relevant packages/vms.

Unfortunately (and fortunately) the problem disappeared (after a restart, never trust someone to do the automatic debugging steps you would do).

I'm rolling the deployment out to the rest of the company this week, and hopefully it will not re-emerge.

Comment: Old question but I had the same problem and what helped me was to append `> log` to my command, so my ansible command looks like this:
`command: /usr/bin/screen -dm run.sh > log`

Answer (score 2):

I'm right now trying to do the same with my setup and hit the same problem.

Further testing has shown, that `sleep 1` right after calling the `screen` helped. It seems the ssh script that ansible calls exits before the screen call is fully detached (or something else, that would explain that the `sleep 1` helps)

I've also found [Can't get Fabric's detached screen session example to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327649/cant-get-fabrics-detached-screen-session-example-to-work) with the same suggestion.