# Run a detached process with fabric and screen

Tags: python, linux, fabric, nohup

According to the [FAQ](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang), from the recommended ways to run a detached process, the only one that works for me is `screen` since I cannot install programs on the server and can't seem to make nohup work. I would like to:

- run(command) so that the command keeps running without blocking.
- Know the pid of the process I am running so I can kill it later.

No combination of nohup redirections and `screen -md command` has worked for me so far.

In particular, running this command line does work when executed directly on the server but not trough the run function of fabric. I believe the process is closed when the function returns and I have no time to see it:

`nohup /opt/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f /home/unicryo/PVSS_projects/GenerateErrors/logstash_conf/logstash-config-minimum.cfg >> test.out 2>&1 &`

Comment: What's your error with using nohup?

Answer (score 1):

You have been unable to `nohup` the process because it's [not really supported](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang) by Fabric.

I'd strongly advise running this command via a process manager ([see Fabric's documentation suggestions](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang)) because it's far easier to manage (e.g. `service logstash stop` versus finding the running command in a screen session) and cleaner, but you should be able to get away with something like the following via Fabric:

```
run("screen -d -m '/opt/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f /home/unicryo/PVSS_projects/GenerateErrors/logstash_conf/logstash-config-minimum.cfg'")
```

Comment: This is not working for some reason. With this command I see the screenlog.0 file being filled when launched directly but not from Fabric, where screen doesn't seem to do anything `"screen -L -d -m yes "`

Comment: You need to add a small sleep after starting screen.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460261